# Nested/Formatted logging

Tags: c++, logging

Maybe this is a trivial question and many/most/all good frameworks can do it, but I'm looking for a logger class/framework (as simple as possible) that **makes it easy** to have a nested logging output, something like

```
[time] A::doSomething start
[time]   doing this
[time]   doing that
[time]   calling B
[time]   B::somethingElse start
[time]     do
[time]     re
[time]     mi
[time]     c::foo start
[time]       ...
[time]     c::foo end
[time]   B::somethingElse end
[time] A::doSomething end
```

The closest I've come to while searching the interwebs are [nested diagnostic contexts in log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html). But a) this is for java and b) I'm not sure if this provides what I'm looking for...

And there's this "When leaving a context, call NDC.pop" in the documentation. I'd like to have more stack-based magic if possible.

Are there any projects out there that can do what I'm looking for?

TIA

Comment: I find a simple singleton class with macros to put calls in based on a debug definition the easiest to create if you need to create one, otherwise just do what the project is already doing.

Comment: The "project" currently uses a veeery simple logger class. I've inherited a pile of code with unclear flow-control und many functions/methods with multiple exit points, pure unfiltered spaghetti code. And right now I'm desperate enough to plaster the code with new logging code to at least get a clue of what's going on :(

Comment: @AdrianAlbrecht: There is nothing wrong with multiple exit points in a method... however long methods are usually bad :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any framework for logging, but I've played with enough pretty printer that I know it's not really difficult.

Supposing the existence of a Logger class that supports the `push` and `pop` operations:

```
class LogNester: private boost::noncopyable {
public:
  LogNester(Logger& l): logger(l) { logger.push(); }
  ~LogNester() { logger.pop(); }

private:
  Logger& logger;
};
```

Usage:

```
void foo() {
  LogNester _(GlobalLogger);

  // do something
}
```

The *one* important point: you need to *name* the variable, `LogNester(GlobalLogger)` will push and pop for this statement only (oups), whereas a named variable will live until the end of the scope.

If you are tired of coming up with new names each time (which I can understand), you can always resort to a macro:

```
#define NESTLOG() LogNester BOOST_PP_CAT(log, __LINE__)(GlobalLogger);
```

Still, it is not exactly... automated as you need to define a `LogNester` object upon entry for each method. In theory, you should be able to magically get the depth as long as you don't mind a little slow down: using the stack call information. With `gcc` this is done using the `backtrace` utility:

```
#include <execinfo.h> // GNU/Linux specific header

inline unsigned depth() {
  void* Stack[64];
  return backtrace(Stack, sizeof(Stack));
}
```

Then, enhance your logging macro:

```
#define LOG(Message_) \
  do { \
    GlobalLogger.log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, depth(), Message_); \
  } while(0)
```

Of course, this quite depends whether the calls are inlined or not.

I personally found that `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` were sufficient for my needs.